# Kunen's proof of $L(\kappa)\subseteq H(\kappa)$?

Tags: set-theory

Theorem II.6.23 in Kunen's Set Theory shows equality of $L(\kappa)$ and $H(\kappa)$ under $V=L$. The first part of the proof asserts that $L(\kappa)\subseteq H(\kappa)$ holds for uncountable cardinals. In order to show this, Kunen fixes $\omega\leq\alpha<\kappa$ s.t. $x\in L(\alpha)$. The existence of such an $\alpha$ is clear to me. Then he says that the following holds:
$$\text{trcl}(x)\subseteq L(\alpha)$$

I cannot see why this is true. Having an infinite $\alpha$ is apparently important, but I don't see why this holds.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just because $L(\alpha)$ is a transitive set with $x\subseteq L(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ is the smallest transitive set containing $x$ as a subset (thus the name “transitive closure”).

Comment: I haven't seen this characterization of the transitive closure yet! It sounds sensible, how does one show this?

Comment: @uniform_on_compacts What is the definition of transitive closure you are working with? If it is $\bigcup_n (\cup^n x),$ just show by induction that if $x\subseteq A,$ with $A$ transitive, then $\cup^n x\subseteq A.$ (Which just amounts to showing in general that if $x\subseteq A$ and $A$ transitive, then $\cup x \subseteq A.$)

Comment: @uniform_on_compacts Kunen defines the transitive closure and proves that it is the smallest transitive set containing x on pg 99 in "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs"

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCarey for pointing this out, apologies for missing that!

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Indeed, we used the union definition, but as Michael clearly points out, the fact that it is the smallest transitive set containing x was also shown in Kunen, my bad for not having checked properly...